# Angular2 / i18n routing - How to make default path "/" display the en-US traductions without en-US in the URL?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm developing an application under angular 13. This application was initially developed in English. We added two new languages (FR | ES ).

To not break the links that customers have to access the application we want to :

```
application.com/ => use en-US trad
application.com/fr-FR => use fr-FR trad
application.com/es-CO => use es-CO trad
```

How it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@ngx-translate`, pages can actually use the same URL (application.com) to show content in different languages.

In somewhere that initializes the app (e.g. `translation-resolver.service.ts`), there should be logic like

```
this.translateService.addLangs(['en-US', 'fr-FR', 'es-CO']);
this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en-US');
const browserLang = this.translateService.getBrowserCultureLang();
if (browserLang != null) {
  let language = "en-US";
  if (browserLang?.includes("fr", 0)) {
    language = "fr-FR";
  } else if (browserLang?.includes("es", 0)) {
    language = "es-CO";
  }
  this.translateService.use(language);
} else {
  this.translateService.use('en-US');
}
```

Then, the page language will follow the language of user's machine or browser.

If you have buttons to switch languages, the callback function of that button should look like

```
onChangeFr() {
  this.translate.use('fr-FR'); // or 'en-US', 'es-CO'
}
```

You may also consider using `localStorage` to store the language preference that users have chosen. If do so, you need to implement logic in initializer function to load the language value from `localStorage` before picking language based on `translateService.getBrowserCultureLang()`, and another logic to store language value to `localStorage` inside `onChangeFr()`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, but we use @angular/localize for the translation.